# CUDA Floating Point Compare

Tags: cuda, floating-point, comparison

I was wondering if anybody has a good implementation of floating point/
double comparison for CUDA. I'd like to use something (semi) standard,
instead of writing my own. I couldn't find something standard, or
endorsed by CUDA. But here are some good resources on the topic:

http://developer.download.nvidia.com/assets/NVIDIA-CUDA-Floating-Point.pdf

http://www.mrupp.info/Data/2007floatingcomp.pdf

something with following header, optimized for running on CUDA
// Usable AlmostEqual function
bool fcmp(double a, double b)

cheers,
Ashkan

Answer (score 5):

There are several ways to compare floating point numbers.  You can look at the *absolute difference* between the numbers.  You can look at the *relative difference* between the numbers, taking the absolute difference divided by whichever number is the reference.  You can look at *bitwise equality* of the floating point representations.

Without knowing why you're comparing two numbers it's hard to say which is best for you.  There is no official CUDA-endorsed way to compare floating point numbers, other than the `==` operator which is defined by IEEE-754.